# how to update local copy of Snapshot when data is changed in firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase for my Angular app. I am using realtime Database because I want to get the update when a node in the database is changed for that I am using `on` listener on the node. it works fine I am getting all the updates real time but the problem is that when the node is changed new snapshot is request as the node content is huge it results in high data usage.

Is there any way to automatically update the local copy of a snapshot whenever the node is changed. this way only changes will be downloaded?

```
    InitApp(data) {
  this.app = data;
  firebase.database().ref('app_con').on('value', (snapshop) => {
    this.app_con = snapshop.val();
    console.log(this.app_con);
  });
  firebase.database().ref('users/user1/userDetails').on('value', (snapshot) => {
    this.user1Snapshot = snapshot;
  });
  firebase.database().ref('users/user2/userDetails').on('value', (snapshot) => {
    this.user2Snapshot = snapshot;
  });
  firebase.database().ref('users/user3/userDetails').on('value', (snapshot) => {
    this.user3Snapshot = snapshot;
  });
  firebase.database().ref('users/user4/userDetails').on('value', (snapshot) => {
    this.user4Snapshot = snapshot;
  });
}
```

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: I have added the code by which I am monitoring node.

Comment: The simple fix here is denormalize your data so only the data you are interested is in provided to the app when it's changed.